# New array created based off old array, ids are different, but changing new array changes old array (python)

Tags: python, pointers

Good afternoon!

The following is my snippet of code:

```
density_new = density_old[:,:,40:55]

for i in range(0,16):
    density_new[:,:,i] = 1020
```

Now, this should only change density_new, because by the way we allocate density_new it has its own memory ID (I double-checked using python's id() command on both variables).  The problem is that when I run the code, it changes both density_old and density_new, and since they have different IDs, I don't know why this is happening.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you copy a list to another one, python will make them refrence the same list so when updating one the other one automatically will be updated, but using `list()` function to copy a list will avoid this trick.

so just try this one:

```
density_new = list(density_old[:,:,40:55])
```

Comment: I did try this trick, but the issue is that now density_new is not an array, it's a list, and assigning values as in the for loop does not work.  Since I use it as an array farther down for a variety of things, I need it to keep its structure.  Is there a way to do that with list?

Comment: I'm not sure but you may use numpy arrays

Comment: Ah, got it, using np.asarray will convert it back to array form.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
import copy

density_new = copy.deepcopy(density_old[:,:,40:55])
```

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html :

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.